# How to shuffle my questions in django quiz?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need to shuffle questions un mt Django quiz. There is my view:

```py
@login_required
def test(request, test_id):
    test_set = get_object_or_404(TestSet, id=test_id)
    questions = test_set.question_set.all()
    user_test, created = UserTest.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, test_set=test_set)
    user_answers = user_test.useranswer_set.all()
    correct_answers = sum(user_answer.selected_answer.is_correct for user_answer in user_answers)
    current_question_index = user_answers.count()
    find_percent = int(int(correct_answers) / len(questions) * 100)

    num_questions = questions.count()
    if current_question_index < num_questions:
        current_question = questions[current_question_index]
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = QuestionForm(request.POST, question=current_question)
            if form.is_valid():
                user_answer = form.cleaned_data['selected_answer']
                user_test.useranswer_set.update_or_create(question=current_question,
                                                          defaults={'selected_answer': user_answer})
                return redirect('test', test_id=test_id)
        else:
            form = QuestionForm(question=current_question)
    else:
        return render(request, 'test_view.html', {'test_set': test_set, 'user_test': user_test, 'questions': questions,
                                                  'show_result': True, 'current_question': None,
                                                  'correct_answers': correct_answers, 'find_percent': find_percent})

    return render(request, 'test_view.html',
                  {'test_set': test_set, 'form': form, 'current_question_index': current_question_index,
                   'current_question': current_question, 'correct_answers': correct_answers})
```

I try to make random questions like:

```
 questions = test_set.question_set.all().order_by('?')
```

But it doesn't work because questions can be repeated. How to solve this problem?

Comment: "Are you indicating that there might be two or more identical questions within the question_set? Is this the reason .order_by('?') isn't effective in this situation?"

Also, do you want a production solution or just for test reason?

Comment: it's ,my pet project

Comment: Are you indicating that there might be two or more identical questions within the question_set? Is this the reason .order_by('?') isn't effective in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiz typically involves querying the questions from your database and then shuffling them using Python's random.shuffle() before rendering or serving them to the user.

So i am creating a demo view and you can modify as per your requirement.

```
import random
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question

def quiz(request):
    all_questions = list(Question.objects.all())
    random.shuffle(all_questions)
    
    context = {
        'questions': all_questions,
    }

    return render(request, 'quiz_template.html', context)
```

Hope this will resolve your doubt.

Comment: When i try to shuffle my questions, it return exception:
TypeError: 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment

Comment: i fixed it by list(), but my qestions repeated again like my code :(